# How to convert content of MultipartFile file into JSON string

Tags: java, json, rest, file, multipart

I have one file Person.Java

```
public class Person {
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
}
```

file is stored at location say : "C:\Users\Person.Java"; This file is not part of the project.

I have written REST API endpoint which is accepting this file as a input and reading this file.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/poc/jsobj", produces = {APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity<ResponseMessage> convertToJson(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

if (!file.isEmpty()) {
    byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
    String completeData = new String(bytes);

    //what should I write here
}}
```

After reading I want to convert content of this file into JSON format.

```
{
"firstName":" ",
"lastName":" "
}
```

so, the requirement is take java file (a class) as input to controller and generate corresponding json String as it's output.

Comment: You can convert java objects to json, not from a .java file. To do this, you have to write your own algorithm.

Comment: You can utilize java libraries that convert the instances of java classes to json objects.

Comment: Thanks Alexiy ...but could you please share one example?